# Linear dependence of the derivatives of a vector valued function

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis, differential-equations, differential-operators

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^5$ be an injective smooth function, and consider the function
$$
g:\mathbb{R}^5\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^5
$$
given by
$$
g(t_1,t_2,t_3,a,b) = f(t_1)+a(f(t_2)-f(t_1))+b(f(t_3)-f(t_1)).
$$
Assume that for all $(t_1,t_2,a)\in\mathbb{R}^3$ there exists $(\hat{t}_1,\hat{t}_2,\hat{a})\in\mathbb{R}^3$ with $(\hat{t}_1,\hat{t}_2,\hat{a})\notin\{(t_1,t_2,a), (t_2,t_1,1-a)\}$ and $\hat{t}_1\neq \hat{t}_2$ such that
$$
f(t_1)+a(f(t_2)-f(t_1)) = f(\hat{t}_1)+\hat{a}(f(\hat{t}_2)-f(\hat{t}_1)).
$$
Under these assumptions can we conclude that for all $\hat{s}:=(\hat{t}_1,\hat{t}_2,\hat{t}_3,\hat{a},\hat{b})\in\mathbb{R}^5$ the derivatives
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial t_1}(\hat{s}),\frac{\partial g}{\partial t_2}(\hat{s}),\frac{\partial g}{\partial t_3}(\hat{s}),\frac{\partial g}{\partial a}(\hat{s}),\frac{\partial g}{\partial b}(\hat{s})
$$
of $g$ are linearly dependent?

Comment: Your assumption is always satisfied for any $f$:  Given $(t_1,t_2,a)$ with $t_1\not=t_2$, just take $(\hat t_1,\hat t_2,\hat a) = (t_2,t_1,1{-}a)$.  For $(t_1,t_2,a)=(t,t,a)$ take $(\hat t_1,\hat t_2,\hat a) = (t,t,a+1)$

Comment: You are right. I forgot to specify this. I meant that the other point can not be a permutation of $t_1,t_2$ and can not lie on the diagonal.